# The differential equation $y''-q(x)y=0.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let   $$y''-q(x)y=0$$be a differential equation with initial conditions  on $0\leq x<\infty,$ as $y(0)=1,y'(0)=1$ where $q(x)$ is a positive monotonically increasing continuous function. Then which of the following are true?

1. $y(x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.
2. $y'(x)\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.
3. $y(x)$ has finitely many zeros in $[0,\infty)$.
4. $y(x)$ has infinitely many zeros in $[0,\infty)$.

Please don't mind, actually I am new in differential equation. I only know that by Picard's theorem the above differential equation has the unique solution, but I don't know what is the solution as I tried by direct hit and trial method. According to me the solution of above differential equation will be some thing in exponential form, so according to me its answer will be $a$, $b$, $c$. But I don't know the exact method. Please help me to solve the above problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no its right...

Comment: [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723118/zeros-of-non-trivial-solution-of-an-ode?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite the ODE as $y''=q(x)y$. When $x=0$, both $y$ and $y'$ are positive. The ODE tells us that $y''$ is also positive. Therefore, the function is increasing, and its derivative is also increasing. As the function gets bigger, $q(x)$ also gets bigger. This leads to $y''$ also getting bigger, which means that $y'$ gets bigger too! There is nothing to stop the growth process; the solution just grows without bound forever. This should give you enough information to determine which of those options are correct.

Comment: i am trying to understand yours answer....thanks a lot....

Comment: but they are positive at zero only...

Comment: how can we say that $y$ and $y^{'}$ are increasing on $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Since $y(0)=1$, $y''(0)>0$. This means that $y'$ is increasing, at least initially. But $y'$ increasing means $y$ is increasing, which means that $y''$ is increasing which goes back to $y'$ increasing. It's like a feedback loop.

Comment: i am not getting the point $y^{'}$ is increasing  on whole interval?  it is correct that $y^{''}(0)>0$

Comment: how $y^{''}(0)>0$ gives that $y^{'}$ is increasing on whole interval?

Comment: It only gives you that $y'$ is initially increasing. That, combined with the fact that $y'(0)>0$ gives you that $y$ is also increasing. There is nothing in the ODE that eventually stop the growth, so we can conclude that all three of $y$, $y'$ and $y''$ increase forever.

Comment: ok its means we will work according to initial condition? we will check behaviours according to initial conditions?

Comment: but i am not fully satisfied about this...

Comment: Yes. Initial conditions determine the behavior of the ODE. For instance, if $y(0)$ were negative, the behavior would be much harder to predict.

Comment: actually i am new in ODE so it is difficult for me to digest these things..

Comment: you are saying that "There is nothing in the ODE that eventually stop the growth"....can you please explane little bit

Comment: I feel like I did in my answer.

Comment: but there is no surety about their behaviours....

Comment: Of course there is. This is what Picard's Theorem says, the solution to the ODE is unique. We can know everything about the behavior of the solutions from the ODE and its initial conditions.

Comment: ok now i am felling comfortable about yours lines"This is what Picard's Theorem says, the solution to the ODE is unique. We can know everything about the behavior of the solutions from the ODE and its initial conditions"...

Comment: your last comment is really very nice one...

Answer (score 2):

$y''(0) = q(0)y(0) > 0$, obviously. Implies
$$\exists \delta >0, x \in (0,\delta) \implies y'(x) > y'(0) = 1 $$
Which implies
$$\forall x \in (0,\delta), y(x) \geq y(0) + x = 1 + x$$

Therfore
$$x \in [0,\delta) \implies y''(x) >0$$

Let
$$A = \{\delta > 0 | x \in [0,\delta) \implies y''(x) > 0\}\\
  a = \sup A$$
It's easy to see that $a \in A$. Since $y''(x)$ is continuous, $y''(a) = 0$. Since $\forall x \in [0,a), y''(x) > 0$. We have for $0 \leq x < a$
$$\begin{align}
y'(x) \geq y'(0) = 1 \tag{1}\\
y(x) \geq y(0) + x = 1 + x \tag{2}\\
\end{align}$$
Since $y$ is continuous, $(2) \implies y(a) > 0 \implies y''(a) >0$. We have a contradiction. Hence $\forall x \in [0,\infty), y''(x) > 0$, which combined with other information from the question implies
$$\forall x \in [0,\infty), y(x) \geq 1 + x\\
 \implies y(x) \rightarrow \infty,\;x \rightarrow \infty\\
 \implies y''(x) \rightarrow \infty,\;x \rightarrow \infty\\
\implies y'(x) \rightarrow \infty,\;x \rightarrow \infty$$