# Zero's of non trivial solution of an second order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What can we say about the zero's of  any non-trivial solution of the linear differential equation$$y^{''}+q(x)y=0$$ (where $q(x)$ is positive monotonically increasing continuous function of $x$). Can we say that it must have infinitely many zeros in $\mathbb{R}?$ For example $y^{''}+y=0$ has $sin(x)$ as a non trivial solution, which has infinitely many zero's. Please help me to prove the general result about infinitely many zero's. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $0<c\le\sqrt{q(x)}$. The infinitesimal angle increment of the complexified phase vector $y'+icy$ is the imaginary part of
$$
\frac{d}{dt}Ln(y'+icy)=\frac{y''+icy'}{y'+icy}=\frac{(-qy+icy')(y'-icy)}{y'^2+c^2y^2}
\\
=\frac{-(q-c^2)yy'+ic(y'^2+qy^2)}{y'^2+c^2y^2}
$$
Thus the angular velocity around the origin is
$$
c+\frac{q-c^2}{y'^2+c^2y^2}cy^2\ge c,
$$
so there are infinitely many revolutions around the origin, each with time smaller $\frac{2\pi}c$, and each revolution gives two zeros of $y$.

---

Or, to state compatibility with the *Sturm–Picone comparison theorem* (where the second equation is $y''+c^2y=0$), each interval of length $\frac{\pi}c$ contains at least a half-revolution and thus at least one zero of $y$.

Comment: ok Thanks a lot sir...

Answer (score 2):

If $q(x)$ is a positive increasing function, then the [Kneser oscillation criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser's_theorem_%28differential_equations%29) or can be used to prove that every solution has infinitely many zeros. Another possibility is to use [Sturm comparison theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem) and compare your equation with $$y''+\varepsilon y=0$$ for positive and sufficiently small $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Can we such an epsilon??......

Comment: Sure, q(x) is positive and increasing. Take epsilon as q(1), for example.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the system
$$
y'=z,\,\, z'=-p(x)y
$$
Infinite zeros are guaranteed if we show that the vector
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}(y,z)=(a,b)
$$
which lives on the unit circle, 
turns infinite times around the origin.

But,
$$
(a,b)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\Longrightarrow
(a',b')=\theta'(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)\\ \Longrightarrow
\theta'=ab'-a'b=\cdots=\frac{y'z-yz'}{y^2+z^2}=\frac{(y')^2+q(x)y^2}{y^2+(y')^2}\ge \frac{(y')^2+q(0)y^2}{y^2+(y')^2}\ge\min\{1,q(0)\}>0.
$$
Thus $\theta(x)\to\infty$, as $x\to\infty$.